# Gibbs free energy of mixing

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry

If we have to ideal gases A and B in two chambers divided by a thin wall. $n_A$,$n_B$ are the number of moles for each gas. I need to find the gibbs free energy of mixing when I remove the barrier.

So I use the following formula for $\Delta G$:

$\Delta G_{mix}= \Delta H_{mix} + -T\Delta S_{mix}$.

So Initially I find the entropy of mixing. Since Entropy is a state variable I observer each sub-system jumping from the initial state (gas in one part of the chamber) to the entire room in a quasistatic way, in order to use the expression: $dU= TdS -pdV$. Then I get for the total mix entopy:

$\Delta S_{mix}= n_AR \ln(\frac V V_A) + n_B R\ln(\frac V V_B)$, where $V=V_A + V_B$

Now I know that in this case the enthalpy of mixing is zero. Of course  I want to also prove that mathematically, therefore I do the following:

$H= TdS +VdP + \Sigma_i \mu_i dN_i$

I assume that for each sub-system the process (expansion) is reversible. I can do that because Enthalpy is a state variable so regardeless whether the system goes from one state to another in a reversible or irreversible way, it's change is the same. So:

$dH=TdS + VdP$, and since the nr. of particles is constant, I leave the last term.

$\Delta H_A = T\Delta S_A + n_ART\ln(\frac P P_{A})$

$\Delta H_B = T\Delta S_B + n_BRT\ln(\frac P P_{B})$.

I assume that summing up these two terms should give me 0. But this is not the case. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You just have to know from Gibbs Theorem that the enthalpy and entropy of a mixture of ideal gases is the same as that of the pure substances comprising the mixture, each at the same temperature and partial pressure as in the mixture.  The same goes for the Gibbs free energy.

Comment: And that would imply what? That since we have no change in the nr. of particles and no interaction among them, for each sub-system the enthalpy doesn't change ?

Comment: That is certainly a correct molecular interpretation.